# display individual comments votes (fivestar) using views

Tags: views, rating

I want to recreate drupal node using views. Under node title there would be average voting result + comments with individual voting. I try to display individual comments votes on a node using view. It always returns 0 no matter what configuration I try. I spent whole day trying to solve it. Can anybody help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: what version of drupal / views / fivestar are you using?